# UIL Math Contest Problem #60 Regional

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

Given the circle O with perpendicular diameters and a chord, find the area of the circle if EF = 8" and DE = 20" (DF = 12"). (integer)

DE is a chord that intersects one of the diameters and shares a point on the circle with another (click on hyperlink below to see a picture).

It is not a 30-60-90 right triangle; it has been tried and does not produce the correct answer.

The correct answer: 377 sq. inches

If you understand how to do this problem or know the proof behind it, please help me with this.

[Link to the image which is the circle to use for reference for this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm462.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle $DOF$ is similar to triangle $DEB$ since they share an angle, and angle $\angle DEB$ is right. Therefore
$${DF\over r} = {2r\over DE},$$
where $r$ is the radius of the circle. From this you can compute $\pi r^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This opened my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Triangles BED and FOD are similar.